# converting images to movies using ffmpeg - passing wildcards to ffmpeg glob -i input using Bash

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, glob

I have a number of non-sequentially numbered image jpgs which have the same starting string and can be identified by eg

```
ls car_drive*.jpg
```

I can assemble into a movie using my bash function as follows which works well

```
ffimage2movie_scaling() {
echo "files input in double quotes"
echo "input and output file "
/usr/bin/nice ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -v quiet -framerate 9 -pattern_type \
glob -i "$1" -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2"  "$2"

}
export -f ffimage2movie_scaling
```

invoked as

```
ffimage2movie_scaling "car_drive*.*" output.mp4
```

I want to implement this so that I can use the stem term "car_drive" to prefix the output mp4 using the following slight edit of the previous function

```
prepare_video_from_images () {
inputStem="$1"
inputFile="$1""*.*"
echo "$inputFile"
outputFile="movie_""$inputStem"".mp4"

/usr/bin/nice ffmpeg -pix_fmt yuv420p -v quiet -framerate 9 -pattern_type \
glob -i "$inputFile"  \
 -c:v libx264 -vf "scale='min(1280,iw)':min'(720,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -crf 18 "$outputFile"
}
export -f prepare_video_from_images
```

However no variant of presenting glob -i with the equivalent input seems to work.  I've tried shopt -s/u extglob,  set -/+f,  adding " wrap around etc etc .  All help greatly appreciated to get it working

Comment: I am not that familiar with `ffmpeg` so I may be mistaken (often am) but I think you are using `glob` which is a part of `ffmpeg` itself, so I can't imagine it would be affected by bash's options and globbing and `shopt` commands. I imagine `ffmpeg` would implement globbing internally so it works on Windows and other places. I may well be wrong!

Comment: @MarkSetchell - I was referring to seeing if the action on the inputFile="$1""*.*"  term might be ameliorated by the use of bash shopt etc mods

Answer (score 0):

Bit of lateral thinking,   I took the glob input that worked in the first example, input it and then carved it up with sed / cut to give me the stem which I could then use in naming the output file.

```
prepare_video_from_images () {
inputStem="$1"
outputStem=$(echo "$inputStem" | sed 's/\*//' | cut -d. -f1 )
echo "$outputStem"
outputFile="movie_""$outputStem"".mp4"

/usr/bin/nice ffmpeg  -pix_fmt yuv420p -v quiet -framerate 9 -pattern_type \
glob -i "$inputStem"  \
 -c:v libx264 -vf "scale='min(1280,iw)':min'(720,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2" -crf 18 "$outputFile"
}
```

invoked as before  by

```
prepare_video_from_images "car_drive*.jp*g"
```